# I am overseas and my U.S bank will not allow me to initiate international wires over the phone

Tags: banking

I am overseas and my U.S bank will not allow me to initiate international wires over the phone.  And I need to send to foreign U.S dollar bank account.  any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your bank provide any alternatives?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it can be answered only by your bank.

Comment: If we knew more information about the source bank and the destination country / bank, we might find that actually the destination bank is on the list of prohibited entities to deal with? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_of_Foreign_Assets_Control) Could you provide more information here?

Comment: I worked in the position of advising members of their options when an international wire is not available. We can advise without asking the bank; we do need to know if the OP is looking for a PUPID or account wire. Provided the destination country or person is not on the OFAC list, the source institution either doesn't provide remittance transfers, or doesn't have a standing account with an international bank (E.g. New York Mellon) that can translate to SWIFT coding. The solution (if the transfer MUST be a wire) is a two-bank wire through an institution that does provide these services.

Comment: If this is reopened (when I worked in finance it was a common enough question), my above comment is an answer.

Comment: Since the OP is wiring to an account, the primary constraint is time to process the wire vs time to arrange for an intermediary institution. Read your fine print. Additionally, if remittance transfer compliance is the issue, you may have to launch the first domestic wire as a single-bank, then launch again from that bank to the SWIFT bank.

Answer (score 1):

As @littleadv said, ask your bank. There may be an alternative mechanism for you to prove your identity, such as having another bank vouch for you through the Medallion system.

But this is really something you should have resolved before leaving the country. For obvious reasons, it may be difficult to do remotely without making prior arrangements.

(Note: it's a good idea to let your bank know when you will be traveling, and where,  so they don't reject your credit card charge from Canada or Uzbekistan as suspicious. That might or might not have also helped with this situation.)